# Two monitors working with my notebook

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a notebook: HP PB 4540s. It contains:

- MB: Hewlett-Packard 17F6
- CPU: Intel Core i5-3230M 2.60GHz
- RAM: DDR3 Kingston 8GB 1333MHz
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000 300MHz
- 1x VGA and 1x HDMI

I plan to buy two [AOC i2369Vm 23"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/AOC-I2369VM-inch-Monitor-50000000/dp/B00BDBWE0Y) monitors. I want to use monitors without the display my notebook has. I quess I will have to connect one monitor using VGA and the other through HDMI. Will it work? Will there be huge difference in quality? Would [this](http://www.dx.com/p/vga-to-hdmi-hd-adapter-cable-w-3-5mm-cable-usb-charging-cable-black-379287#.VguRRd_tlBd) be a solution to display differences? What would you recommend me to do/buy so I can work on two monitors?

Comment: Hi Mish, your question isn't concerning a hardware recommendation as it is right now. However, you could reword it to ask for solutions to your problem so that your question won't get closed.

Comment: @Adam ok, I tried to add a recommendation question, I hope it's ok now

Comment: You got it wrong. You need VGA to HDMI converter. Your computer has VGA output then your converter should have VGA input. Check this topic: http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-1716596/vga-computer-hdmi-monitor.html

Comment: But the most important part is that this monitor has VGA input. Just use VGA to VGA cable (check my answer).

Comment: @belford my notebook has one VGA and one HDMI and I want two monitors with the same representation and I am afraid that a monitor with VGA would look much worse so I want to get rid of the difference by making VGA change to HDMI

Comment: @belford and the link in my question leads to VGA to HDMI converter, it literally says "Can convert VGA singal on desktop PC, laptops, DVD to HD digital signal" so I don't know what I got wrong

Comment: I just wanted to note that HDMI to VGA and VGA to HDMI are not the same. The second part is that converter wouldn't make the quality better. I'd recommend to buy a good VGA cable. Check this topic http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-2485278/switching-vga-hdmi-converter-graphics-card-improve-quality.html

Comment: VGA supports 1080p as it is and if you have an opportunity to connect VGA-VGA, you won't notice any difference.

Answer (score 4):

I personally use the [Plugable UD-3900 USB 3.0 Universal Docking Station](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ECDM78E), I find it convenient if you have many devices to connect to your laptop. Regarding the graphics:

- HDMI port supports resolutions up to 2560x1440* and DVI/VGA port supports display resolutions up to 2048x1152 / 1920x1200; wired Ethernet port supports 10/100/1000Mbps speeds
- Full support for Windows 10, 8.1, 8, 7, & legacy XP systems. Surface RT, Mac OS X, and Linux/Unix are not supported. Docking station suggested for use with web and productivity software; not recommended for gaming
- *2560x1440 output only available when using a single HDMI display. If dual displays are connected, each will be limited to a maximum resolution of 1920x1200. 2560x1440 output requires a "High Speed" HDMI cable. 2560x1440 mode operates at a 50Hz refresh rate; all lower modes support 60Hz refresh. 2560x1440 output requires current DisplayLink drivers and attached monitor must natively support 2560x1440 via HDMI input

[image: Plugable UD-3900 USB 3.0 Universal Docking Station rear]
[image: Plugable UD-3900 USB 3.0 Universal Docking Station front]

Comment: I know that there are docking stations but they are very expensive and I need it only to solve VGA looking like HDMI on display screen. My question is on converters or something just to do that.

Answer (score 1):

An Update:

This monitor has a D-Sub input. In this case you just need a VGA-VGA cable. VGA supports 1080p as it is - you won't notice any difference since the cable is of good quality.
[image]

---

1. As far as I know it it can only recognize either VGA or HDMI. [Check this topic](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/Two-Displays-on-Probook-4540s/td-p/5078189). The best thing you can do is to ask on HP forums about drivers - it would be better to do it before making a purchase. Check this part from the linked topic.

> I discovered that if you run the install of the Intel HD Graphics 4000
>   driver version 10.18.010.3464 it will initialize both the VGA and the
>   HDMI and they will both work until you reboot your machine.

2. VGA supports 1080p. The quality of the signal begins to drop off above 1920x1080. Is it worth to buy a good quality cable.
3. Similar question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/782227/probook-4540s-monitors).
4. The adapter may be unnecessary if you find appropriate drivers.

Comment: I think I have read that it is possible to use both VGA and HDMI but what I am tryign to solve is a difference in display quality. I don't understand this are of computers so I don't know if I can use something to make VGA act like HDMI, so it looks the same on monitors. I know that there are docking stations but they are very expensive and I need it only to solve this.

Comment: VGA can support 1920x1080. You can do some calibration to make the image sharpest: http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/clock_phase.php

Comment: OK, thank you, I'll try to relax. I'll see if there will be any problems after I'll buy the monitors in a few weeks. I will definitely try to calibrate it according to the link.

Comment: I believe it's not the only dup on SU.